# React MUI - Consistent Tab Content Height

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs, height

I understand that ideally should be placed at the top of the page.  However, Assume they are place in the middle of the page.  When changing from a tab with a lot of content, to a tab with little content, the scrollable area disappears.  Is there anyway to preserve the white space?

https://codesandbox.io/s/labtabs-material-demo-forked-y39i2g?file=/demo.tsx

Here is a code sandbox example.

Step 1 scroll down to tabs.

Step 2 scroll down tab 1 content( leave tabs visible)

Step 3 click tab 2 (Mouse no longer is hovering over tabs because vertical scroll content vanishes)

Edit: I am able to change my root div min height to whatever I need hard-coded. I feel like this hacky though and not dynamic to the tallest tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `minHeight` `style` to tab2 and tab3 to be the height of tab1 using `useRef`

```
const tabRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
const [tabHeight, setTabHeight] = React.useState(0);
React.useEffect(() => {
    setTabHeight(tabRef.current.clientHeight)
}, [tabRef]);


<TabPanel value="1" ref={tabRef}></TabPanel>
<TabPanel value="2" sx={{ minHeight: tabHeight }}></TabPanel>
<TabPanel value="3" sx={{ minHeight: tabHeight }}></TabPanel>
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/labtabs-material-demo-forked-40kpwc?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: This only works if you already know what panel is the tallest. Is there a way to get the tallest panel, without having to display them all and get the tallest that way?